# jQuery MouseEnter Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I am writing an plugin for websites which uses jQuery I am wondering, why some of the sites which are using the script get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'mouseenter'
```

The code:

```
plugin.setBehavior = function() {
    jQuery('#divname').mouseenter(function() {
        show();
    });
}
```

Are there any versions of jQuery without the mouseenter event or what could be the reason for the failure?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
plugin.setBehavior = function() {
    jQuery('#divname').bind("mouseenter",function() {
        show();
    });
}
```

also `live` or `delegate` if `bind` won't work

Comment: please don't be rude and don't insult. Please mind your language. While you might feel frustrated by the fact that the person who downvoted your answer didn't leave a comment, you shouldn't react in that manner. I understand your frustration and I agree with you. It is good to always leave a comment when downvoting. Hopefully the person who did that will explain.

Comment: I deleted the previous comment

Comment: I did not downvote but i do say that live, delegate and bind are deprecated in jquery 1.7 and no longer used.

Comment: So should I use bind or do I have to check for the jQuery version used, so the script uses bind or on depending on the version?

Comment: The `bind` was added in Jquery 1.4.3 (http://api.jquery.com/bind/). `For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().` that wrote for Jquery > 1.7